# Are there any DC offset compensation algorithm for 5G NR?

Tags: ofdm

Unlike LTE, DC subcarrier is used in 5G-NR. DC subcarrier may suffer from local oscillator leakage. Local oscillator leakage gives rise to DC offset.
Are there any DC offset compensation algorithms for 5G NR?

Please note that the following question does not have any satisfactory answer.

[What type of LO lekage Correction algorithm is used in 5GNR?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84240/what-type-of-lo-lekage-correction-algorithm-is-used-in-5gnr)

Thanks.